# S3 Sync Not Writable Warning

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am trying to use s3cmd sync (vanilla command remote to local), but for each file I get a `not writable: Operation not permitted` warning (see below). The files appear to download correctly, however, and if I do an `ls` on the file it is there. I tried using the `--disable-multipart` flag but this made no difference. I am using s3cmd version  1.5.0-rc1.

Is there any reason why I might be receiving these warnings?

```
WARNING: MD5 signatures do not match: computed=11ff15bf.., received="b119cb85b109c6.."
WARNING: ./path/part-r-00003.gz.parquet not writable: Operation not permitted
s3://bucket/path/part-r-00003.gz.parquet -> <fdopen>  [31 of 72] 36101458 of 36101458   100% in 2s    16.30 MB/s  done
```

Answer (score 33):

A likely reason is that the S3 objects have been stored with filesystem attributes. When you sync them to a local directory, by default s3cmd sync will try to restore these attributes, including uid,gid ownership.

To prevent s3cmd from doing this, run it with the --no-preserve option, e.g.:

```
s3cmd sync --no-preserve s3://bucket/my/key/prefix .
```

Comment: This worked for me; believe it should have been marked as the answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Should be marked as such.